# Magento configurable product - update associated products?

Tags: magento, product, configurable

So here's my scenario:

- I have a configurable product with ~50.000 associated products.
- This needs to be synced on a periodic basis with ERP. (So the ERP sends info about which simple products should be associated to configurable product)

The number of associated products that need to be synced is too large to use the usual Magento function for this:

$product->setConfigurableProductsData($data);

Where $data is the array of products that should be associated to configurable $product.

Anybody aware of a way/function to (programmatically) insert new associations (as opposed to above functions which resets all existing ones) and delete existing associations where needed?